# .each() function showing first object 3 times, instead of all 3 objects

Tags: jquery

A query of my WordPress custom fields, generates this array:

```
Array ( [genre] => Rock [concert_city] => New York [concert_date] => 01-16-2014 [start_time] => 8:00 PM )   Array ( [genre] => Jazz [concert_city] => Chicago [concert_date] => 12-12-2013 [start_time] => 7:00 PM )  Array ( [genre] => Pop [concert_city] => Los Angeles [concert_date] => 11-16-2013 [start_time] => 8:00 PM )
```

This array is stored in:

```
$array = array();
```

Need to get this data into jQuery.

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
            var event = <?php echo json_encode($array) ?>;

            $.each(event,function( index, value ){
               console.log(event);
            });
        });
```

This only shows me the first object 3 times, instead of all 3 objects. How can I iterate across all three objects?

And then I need to change them from index:value, into value(concert_date) : value(concert_city), but right now I'm stuck getting only the first object in my array 3 times, instead of 3 objects.

**EDIT**: I ran console.log(value), and it printed the values from the first array, nothing for the other two arrays.

Comment: @smerny Should have been var event. Fixed.

Comment: `console.log(value)`. `event` seems to be the whole array, so `console.log(event)` inside the callback would print the complete array three times.

Comment: @chowwy, if you are only seeing a single object (not your entire array) when logging `event`, then that seems to be all you are getting as a result of `json_encode($array)`

Comment: Your php looks very fishy. aren't there supposed to be some commas in there? and how are you storing two arrays in a single var? that makes no sense.

Comment: *"it printed the values from the first array, nothing for the other two arrays"* Then `$array` doesn't contain all the three arrays/objects. Make sure it does.

Comment: @chowwy, have you checked the value of $array and event in your browser's debugger or console? Are you sure they actually contain the values that you think they do?

Comment: @valverij - The array at the top of my question is the result of print_r($array)

Comment: Are you sure? If I have three arrays inside another array, I get a different output: http://codepad.org/PwULjFRO. Your output is missing the outer array somehow. The only way I can think of how your output is created is that you use `print_r($array)` in a loop, which means that `$array` always contains one array, not all three of them.

Comment: I mean the value interpreted directly by the browser, not through a PHP function.

Comment: @FelixKling I think you're right. Am going to double check that code now.

Comment: Stop thinking about your php. Act as if it doesn't exist, because to javascript, it doesn't. Now, look at the javascript that your server is returning. What does `event` contain exactly? console.log it as a whole.

Comment: @KevinB I think you and Felix were correct about my storing the arrays improperly. I think once my array is correct, js will show the correct objects.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you mean

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var event = <?php echo json_encode($array) ?>;

    $.each(event, function( index, value ){
        console.log(value); // use 'value' not 'event'.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks; it still only returns the values for the first array. Nothing for the others.

Comment: @chowwy first array? what do you mean by first array. I only see one. Where is the second?

Comment: Dump out console.log(event) and copy that into your question. I think the array you expect it to be is not what it seems.

Comment: Can you post the actual output of the console.log(event) call please?

Comment: @JasonEvans You're right. It says Object and has key=value pairs for the first entry, and has it 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you printing the event? Print the index/value based on your requirement:

```
 console.log(value);
```